# How to authenticate mobile client against asp.net webapi portal with UseGoogleAuthentication enabled?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, google-authentication

Following [this guide](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on) I have created asp.net mvc5 webapi portal with UseGoogleAuthentication enabled and trying to implement API usage by authenticated users only:
https://db.tt/ncE1TlNi
https://db.tt/8vRq1beS

Template generated by Visual Studio works fine and I can create accounts/authenticate but I didn't find any information on how should I implement same thing from the mobile client and call API as authenticated user (API intended for mobile authenticated users).

Thank you for any guides and suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/09/20/understanding-security-features-in-spa-template.aspx) to understand OWIN security middleware. In mobile application you can retrieve access token from url fragment after authentication.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/09/20/understanding-security-features-in-spa-template.aspx

Comment: As I understood every authentication process based on web browser. Is it the only option to authenticate on mobile client side? If yes then I should have mobile optimized sign-in (sign-up) page, right?

Comment: For example you can create on server side page access_token.html and rewrite redirect url after authentication to this page. In mobile app you can verify this page and retrieve token from url.
Thereafter you could close additional window and transfer token to your app and save it in app memory.Thereafter  you can use token for another requests to the server.